# libclntsh.so.12.1 : cannot open shared object file error when running sample of node-oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

My goal is to connect to a oracle database on a VMWare guest machine (OpenSuse) from Ubuntu.

For now I have only installed the [oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb) driver, and was trying to run the [example connect program](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/connect.js) given.

The steps that I am following are from the github [INSTALL](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#-3-node-oracledb-installation-on-linux-with-instant-client-zip-files) page. What I have done till now are these :

1) Since I have node.js already installed I skipped the [step 3.1](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#31-install-nodejs).

2) I have successfully downloaded and extracted the ***basic*** and ***sdk*** as mentioned in [step 3.2](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#32-install-the-free-oracle-instant-client-zips).

3) Since I couldn't find any package named `libaio` but I did found `libaio1`. So I installed `libaio1`.

4) I made the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and the contents of it on my PC is `/opt/oracle/instantclient`.

5) As mentioned in [step 3.3](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#33-install-the-driver); even though it wasn't mandatory in my case; I made two environment variables: `OCI_LIB_DIR` with contents `/opt/oracle/instantclient` and `OCI_INC_DIR` with contents `/opt/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include`.

6) Installed `node-oracledb`.

I am trying to run the example connect program. The code that I am using is here https://github.com/ishanatmuz/oracle-test. When I run `node connect.js` I am getting this error.

```
/home/ishan/node.js/oracle-test/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:28
throw err;
          ^
Error: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ishan/node.js/oracle-test/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:23:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (modullibclntsh.so.12.1e.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Since I haven't started the VMware guest machine yet; I was hoping of getting an error regarding no such database instance found. And then only after that run the VMWare machine and connect to the database inside it. But instead I am getting the error of `cannot open shared object file` for `libclntsh.so.12.1`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My first suspicion would be that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not actually set or exported correctly. Triple-check it is set and the directory is readable by the actual shell that attempts to start node.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2
```

You need to do this in any shell that starts Node.js.

I'd also check what other Oracle libraries are installed on the machine and make sure you don't have clashes.

Using ldconfig to set the path globally will almost certainly be easier than setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  You can do something like:

```
sudo sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
sudo ldconfig
```

See the [Instant Client install](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst) instructions for details.

If you have optional Net configuration files like `sqlnet.ora` or `tnsnames.ora`, they can be put in a directory `/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2/network/admin` which is a default location for configuration files.  See [Optional Oracle Net Configuration](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#tnsadmin).

Update: if you install the Instant Client 19.3 RPM packages, the `ldconfig` step is automatically done. (You still need/could/should do it for a 19.3 ZIP file install)

Instant Client 19 will connect to Oracle Database 11.2 or later, so use Instant Client 19 unless you have a special requirement for an older version.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't accepted your answer. This indeed was the problem. I did figured it out a little sooner than your answer. Forgot to accept this as a solution. Sorry to keep you waiting.

Answer (score 6):

export works only for one process. It seems, it doesn't present at your terminal window (it is separate process).
So, you should execute following again before starting `node connect.js` (in the same terminal window where you going to start node):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: @Zolbayar: To make it permanent, you can add it to your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc